# What it means to 'drop support for SSL 3.0' and 'add support for TSL'

Tags: ios, ssl, amazon-ec2, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

Hundreds of articles have popped up over the last 24 hours claiming that:

> Apple will be switching off SSL 3.0 support in favor of the more secure transport layer security
>   (TSL) protocol on Wednesday, Oct. 29, noting developers will have to build in support by that time
>   to ensure uninterrupted push notification service continues.

But none of them go into further detail about the implications for developers and what actually needs to be done beyond 'build in support'.

I have various applications hosted at on AWS and on Parse to support our push notifications.  I'm sorry if this is very general but I will edit and add more detail as I start to get some responses:
What exactly do I need to **do** to continue support for my push notifications?  I don't know much about SSL/TSL.

Thanks!

Comment: Simply run this against your services and check the protocol support section: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/